# how to add entry to object inside array using jq

Tags: json, jq

Title says it all. So far I get this:

```
echo '[{"a": "A", "b": "B"}, {"c": "C", "d": "D"}]' | jq '.[] + {x:"X"}'
```

Which will result to this:

```
{
  "a": "A",
  "b": "B",
  "x": "X"
}
{
  "c": "C",
  "d": "D",
  "x": "X"
}
```

but it will not "wrap" the result in array and also does not add comma after each entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jq '[.[] + {x:"X"}]'
```

Or you could use `map`

Comment: Thank you. Can you plase also add map version just for clarity?

Comment: @WakanTanka: You can just do `map(.+ {x:"X"})`

Comment: thank you both. I've found that this also works `jq '.[] += {x:"X"}'` Can you please briefly explain why my original approach is not working? Because if I use `jq '.'` then the output is correct JSON but when I use `jq '[.]'` then the output is same JSON but nested in one more array.

Comment: That's a good point about using `+=` here.  To understand all this, I'd suggest reading the relevant parts of the online jq manual while using the `debug` filter so you can see exactly what's going on at each step.

Comment: @peak can you please post how can I use debug in those 3 cases? I'm trying to run following but I got errors: `jq 'debug [.[] + {x:"X"}]'`

Comment: You could start with `jq '.[] | debug'`. For further assistance, please consult the manual and perhaps other resources, e.g. the tutorial, the jq FAQ and other resources that are part of the wiki (notably the Cookbook), etc.